# PHP merge/rewrite arrays to one by condition

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I want to merge them to one where values are 1.

Example:

I have 3 arrays:

```
$array1 = [1,0,0,1,0];
$array2 = [0,0,0,1,0];
$array3 = [0,1,0,0,0];
```

There are "n" number of arrays.

So wanted output will be:

```
$array = [1,1,0,1,0]
```

---

More detail:

*This is my basic idea of merging user permissions. Each array represents group which user is part of and each key in array is permission. Each value of array represents true/false if user have permission.*

Thank you for your code / suggestions / ideas.

Comment: How about some `foreach`. Seriously - those are 2 lines of code (actually 3 if you count the result array initialization)

Comment: "Each value of array is true/false", `[1,0,0,1,0]`. Integers and booleans are 2 distinct types.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with above ^.

Comment: @zerkms Its about representation. Don't be litteral.

Comment: I'm not sure how to be non-literal in programming.

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak - I believe that zerkms point is that you should at least make some effort yourself for something as trivial as this before asking for help

Comment: This would also be easier still if your "numbered" arrays were nested arrays under a single permissions array, especially as there can be many of them

Comment: @MarkBaker its a rule based permission idea. So each group have permissions. Each user can be in multiple groups. Merge group permissions and you have permissions for user.

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak and now it's my turn to reveal the Mark's point: instead of having `$array1`, `$array2`, ... `$arrayN` it might be a better idea to have an array with nested arrays. Since that's what arrays were invented for.

Comment: If this was a nested array, you could easily use array_reduce() to walk through it to get your $array with the permissions checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $array1 = [1,0,0,1,0];
    $array2 = [0,0,0,1,0];
    $array3 = [0,1,0,0,0];
    $result = array();  
    $n = 3; $tmp = 0;
    $result = array();

    for($count = 0; $count < count($array1); $count++) {    
        for($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)
            $tmp = ${"array" . $i}[$count] || $tmp;
        $result[] = $tmp;
    }

    var_dump($result);

?>
```

Output:

```
array(5) { [0]=> bool(true) [1]=> bool(true) [2]=> bool(false) [3]=> bool(true) [4]=> bool(false) }
```

Comment: That actually is funny: the input arrays with integers that are actually booleans and result as a  strings that represent integers that are also actually booleans :-D

Comment: And now it's even more inconsistent: result is either boolean true or integer 0.

Comment: @zerkms Better?! And if it is so bad why don't your write your own answer?!

Comment: Or you could completely eliminate `?: false` part and it will stay the same. So, slightly better, but might be improved even more :-)

Comment: Now I can go to bed :-)

Comment: Yeah, I think so. Not sure why helping making a better answer makes you angry though :-(

Comment: Except that there can be "n" arrays, this will work only for 3.

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak Thanks for the stealth edit: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27900497/2

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak except that you explicitly stated that you have exactly 3 arrays.

Comment: Read question. I wrote an EXAMPLE. Now you are incorect.

Comment: Oh god, I'm incorrect, but you cannot ask clear questions. Sorry, but it's hard to help you. I'm out, have fun.

Comment: Thank you. I don't need code tho. Simplest answer will be **LOGICAL OR**.